# Optimizing django db queries

Tags: mysql, django, django-views

I am trying to optimize my db queries(mysql) in a django app.

This is the situation:

I need to retrieve some data about sales, stock about some products on a monthly basis. This is the function

```
def get_magazzino_month(year, month):
    from magazzino.models import ddt_in_item, omaggi_item, inventario_item
    from corrispettivi.models import corrispettivi_item, corrispettivi
    from fatture.models import fatture_item, fatture, fatture_laboratori_item
    from prodotti.models import prodotti
    qt = 0
    val = 0

    products = prodotti.objects.all()
    invents = inventario_item.objects.all().filter(id_inventario__data__year=year-1)
    fatture_lab = fatture_laboratori_item.objects.all().order_by("-id_fattura__data")

    for product in products:
        inv_instance = filter_for_product(invents, product)
        if inv_instance:
            qt += inv_instance[0].quantita
        lab_instance = fatture_lab.filter(id_prodotti=product).first()
        prezzo_prodotto = (lab_instance.costo_acquisto/lab_instance.quantita - ((lab_instance.costo_acquisto/lab_instance.quantita) * lab_instance.sconto / 100)) if lab_instance else product.costo_acquisto
    return val, qt
```

The problem is where I need to filter all the data to get only the product I need. It seems that the .filter option makes django requery the database, although all of the data is there. I tried making a function to filter it myself, but although the queries diminish, loading time increases dramatically.

This is the function to filter:

```
def filter_for_product(array, product):
    result = []
    for instance in array:
        if instance.id_prodotti.id == product.id:
            result.append(instance)
    return result
```

Has anyone ever dealt with this kind of problem?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your problem. But for  `invents=...` and `fatture_lab=...` which appears just before your loop, you can remove `.all()` from both of them. just use `objects.filter(...)` and `objects.order_by(..)`

Comment: the problem is that my data takes too long being processed, and I think it comes from the lot of queries being done. I modified invents and fatture_lab, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to return a queryset of related objects and [`Prefetch()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) to further control the operation.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

products = prodotti.objects.all().annotate(
    Prefetch(
        'product_set',
        queryset=inventario_item.objects.all().filter(id_inventario__data__year=year-1),
        to_attr='invent'
    )
)
```

Then you can access each product's invent like `products[0].invent`

Answer (score 1):

Using [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) will help optimize your queries

A good example of what select_related() does and how to use it is available at [simpleisbetterthancomplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/05/16/django-tip-3-optimize-database-queries.html).